# Why we need a probabilistic model for queues

Tags: probability, probability-theory, queueing-theory

Good evening.
I am thinking about the probabilistic queuing model M/M/n with n servers, arrival  rate $\lambda$ and service rate $\mu$.
The model allows to estimate the waiting time in the queue and the minimal number of servers that you need for the system not to explode (which is has to be greater then $\frac{\mu}{\lambda})$.

My question is: why we need a probabilistic model? (the minimum number of servers is intituive also without knowing probability)

The probabilistic model allows to have information about the expected waiting time?

Which is the phenomena that a probabilistic model like this one is able to capture?

Comment: As you might expect, the probabilistic model allows you to calculate _probabilities_ such as the probability to see a queue length of $K$, or the probability to be occupied for more than $100*\lambda$ etc.

Comment: One often uses probabilistic models when modelling the details of a complicated deterministic process are too complicated and irrelevant for the practical purpose we want to solve. Imagine that you have to model every call to a server with a model about the psychology of the user, that would be unwieldy. But if it turns out that the details do not matter and only the distribution of arrivals matter, then you can do that with a probabilistic model.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have another doubt. Why it is used the exponential distribution to model intearrival times and not for instance independent gaussians? I know about the memoryless property of the exponential but whst is the real meaning of this property? Thanks again

Comment: @m91c Specifically the Gaussian distribution wont work because it also has a probability to see _negative_ interarrivals. The exponential is a simple model, but indeed there are others, depending on the situation.